# angular js http request from aspx method

Tags: model-view-controller, angularjs

I have a page locations.aspx that has a method behind it in locations.aspx/getData. when I use the code

```
$http.jsonp($scope.url)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(data);
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
```

with the $scope.url being locations.aspx/getData it loads the html page of the aspx page but doesn't access the method. I can access the method using

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $scope.url,
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (p) {
    var temp = $.parseJSON(p.d);
    $scope.allItems.push(temp);
},
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

but the data never updates or binds on the view side. An example on the html is

```
    <select ng-model="selectLocation" id="selectLocation" ng-change="onLocationChange()">
                        <option></option>
                        <option ng-repeat="l in allItems">{{l.location}}</option>
</select>
```

After the ajax call allItems array does have an item in it but the view never updates.

**My ajax call headers are**

Request URL:localhost:41796/locations.aspx/getData

Request Method:POST

Status Code:200 OK

Request Headersview source

Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8

Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private, max-age=0

Connection:Close

Content-Length:270

Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8

**and my $http headers are**

Request URL:localhost:41796/locations.aspx/getData

Request Method:GET

Status Code:200 OK

Request Headersview parsed

GET /locations.aspx/getData HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:41796

Connection: keep-alive

Response Headersview parsed

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0

Cache-Control: private

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 7177

Connection: Close

Comment: I'm guessing `$http.jsonp` defaults to `type: "GET"` and you don't have the getData method exposed via GET?  What happens when you hit `locations.aspx/getData` in a browser, do you get the HTML without the method being called?

Comment: I edited my question, I was looking in the headers and I see that they are not the same which could be giving me the alternate response? I also did try getData in the browser and it did bring up the html without the method being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion above, it seems you're using ASP.NET and running into specific issues with it.

ASP.NET can be pretty picky sometimes about what it will parse and what it won't -- especially when it comes to MVC (which it doesn't appear that you're using here, but perhaps [WebMethod] (what I assume you're using) has the same kinds of issues).

Instead of messing with jQuery's `$.ajax`, you can use Angular's `$http` in the same way:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: $scope.url,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
})
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert(data);
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
```

Check this: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#Parameters for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up having to put it as headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}. I couldn't really find any good documentation on it but got lucky on a search